# How to search a matrix block with a specific handle?

Tags: matrix, queries

I want to query a specific matrix block using text search which will search all the searchable fields in that particular block and give me output in the form of blocks that I can further process.

I tried this

```
 {% set MatrixBlocks = craft.matrixBlocks()
.type('metaData')
.search(query)
.all() %}
```

But when I dump each block, I am seeing so many fields and not fields only from the particuar block (metaData) that I want to query.

What is the correct query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the [fieldId of the Matrix block you're searching through](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/1789).

```
{% set MatrixBlocks = craft.matrixBlocks()
.fieldId(123)
.type('metaData')
.search(query)
.all() %}
```

Comment: That did it :) Many thanks.